# Changing a oneway bound TextBlock value from code behind.

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a TextBlock and its Text property is bound to a ViewModel property. The binding is Oneway.
When I change the Text property of the Control from the xaml.cs the binding gets broken. If the binding is TwoWay I don't have this problem but the source property is updated too. Is it possible to have OneWay binding and change the target property value without braking the binding?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a workaround, like setting the Binding to **TwoWay** and ignore the update in the property. Something like this:

```
private string textValue;

public string TextValue
{
    get { return textValue; }
    set
    {
        :
    }
}
```

Now the Property can no longer be set by the view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't change the setter.

Answer (score 0):

Although no code is provided, this scenario typically occurs when you have bound a control to a view model and at a later stage your logic tries to update the value in the control programmatically.

You should not try to do this, that is define multiple sources of the value for a control. If you bind the control to a property on the view model, then to update the value in the control you should update the field in the view model.

> If you were to set the value of a bound control programmatically at runtime so that it no longer matched the bound object value, when some other event causes the control binding to be re-evaluated, the value that you have provided programmatically would be overwritten again, you could easily end up with a scenario where the value you provided programmatically is never visible to the user.

In this scenario you should either:

1. Add a *new* property to the view model, bind this value to the control, then your program logic can set this value equal to the original property when the data is loaded, and updated when you need to
2. Not use bindings at all, always write to the control programatically that way you tightly control when the value is updated.

There is a workaround to this if you absolutely must have one. if you are using compiled bindings (`x:Bind`), then because the bindings are *compiled* it is possible to call `SetValue` on the bound dependency property at runtime and the previously compiled bindings will still be evaluated. However I advise against exploiting this because it makes your code a lot harder to follow and debug, when bindings are used, we tend not to look for code that directly addresses and sets control values.

Comment: In [uwp] you can set the dependency property values without affecting bindings useing the `SetValue` method on the dependency object.